# How to authenticate kerberos principal in python

Tags: python, kerberos

I installed kerberos module, and tried authentication referring to [this document](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_kerberos.html).

Given that:
principal: username@A.B.com
password: mypassword123

What I tried is:

```
>>> __, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSClientInit("username@A.B.com")
>>> kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
kerberos.GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server krbtgt/B.com@A.B.com not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))
```

When I authenticate my kerberos principal in a terminal, it works well.

```
root@server:/home1/user:$ kinit username@A.B.com
Password for username@A.B.com:

root@server:/home1/user:$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: username@A.B.com

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/02/2021 21:45:00  06/03/2021 21:44:57  krbtgt/A.B.com@A.B.com
    renew until 06/09/2021 21:44:57
```

The difference between the two is, when tried in python, it says

> 'Server krbtgt/B.com@A.B.com not found in Kerberos database'

`A` is omitted in this error log.

I cannot find a well-explained document of python kerberos module..

Also, I don't get where to put my password.
Any link or comment appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that

```
sparkSession = SparkSession \
.builder.appName("working_with_oracle") \
.master('local[*]') \
.config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", '2000') \
.config('spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat', 'true') \
.config("spark.kerberos.keytab" , '/tmp/krb5cc_1000') \
.config("spark.kerberos.principal" , 'xxx') \
.config("spark.kerberos.access.hadoopFileSystems" , 'webhdfs://xxxx:50070') \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()
```